# Change cell background color depends custom area and dynamic value on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to dynamic view of table.
If there is a value row must be change color and next row different color.
For example; there is 10 records row,

1. backgroundcolor is black
2. backgroundcolor is white
3. backgroundcolor is black

Record row value is in located A4. So a4 value may be change and table must be just how many number has it.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].